# Simplest way to create json file from structured raw file in Java?

Tags: java, regex, json, split

example file,

```
x1  x2  y1  y2
12  20  30  40
13  14  15  16
```

I want to create a json structure out of it like so,

```
{ "coordinates" : 
  [
    {"x1" : 12 , "x2" : 20 , "y1":30 , "y2":40},
    {"x1" : 13 , "x2" : 14 , "y1":15 , "y2":16},
  ]
}
```

Default solution is to do splitting and joining the raw file. Unfortunately structured data is not 100% clean, sometimes irregular space is there in values too. What is the cleanest way to handle this kind of conversion, Any lightweight JAVA library does this job?

Comment: A regex is not the right tool for this task. You probably want to write a little parser (if there isn't one available already).

Comment: if the input isn't clean, then GIGO applies - garbage in, garbage out. No matter what you end up with for the output end of things, you have to make sure your inputs are clean, which means rolling your own parser to decompose the inputs to something that can be easily json-encoded.

Comment: Are you interested in the JSON parsing library?

Comment: Yes, ultimately for JSON parsing I have to use JSON library like Jackson

Comment: Are the key's name dynamic?

Comment: @MarcB - Assuming that data is clean, what is the good solution for this?

Comment: It is really easy to do in python with dictionaries, but I am interested in solution in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create some POJO classes that is replica of JSON string and use GSON or Jackson library to convert it into JSON string.

Simply read the file line by line, get the coordinate and populate the below POJO class's object.

sample code:

```
class Coordinates {
    private ArrayList<XY> coordinates;

    // getter & setter    
}

class XY {
    private int x1, x2, y1, y2;

    public XY(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    // getter & setter    
}
```

Sample code:

```
Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates();
ArrayList<XY> list = new ArrayList<XY>();
list.add(new XY(12, 20, 30, 40));
list.add(new XY(13, 14, 15, 16));
coordinates.setCoordinates(list);
```

### [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

```
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(coordinates));
```

### [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

```
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(coordinates));
```

output:

```
{
  "coordinates": [
    {
      "x1": 12,
      "x2": 20,
      "y1": 30,
      "y2": 40
    },
    {
      "x1": 13,
      "x2": 14,
      "y1": 15,
      "y2": 16
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I got it working as you said, just that I had to make fields of the POJO public, or I guess have to configure the fields with visibility ANY.

Comment: You are working in Java world. Follow the OOP principles. It's breaks the secutiry. `public` variable can be accessed form anywhere in an uncontrolled manner. Keep it `private` and use proper `getter/setter` method.